# Try-catch block isn't "catching" the error from a delete operation

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I am currently trying to figure out an error that I am getting. As a temporary fix, I wanted to wrap the delete operation in a try-catch but for some reason the error still goes through rather than being caught.

If anyone has any insight to this behaviour or how to get around it it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

This is my current code:

```
 try {
            item?.delete(flush: flush)
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            log.error "Inventory: {} couldn't be deleted", item, e
        }
```

The error I am getting is the following:

`Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

Answer (score 0):

From your description I see that you're catching `DataIntegrityViolationException`, but in reality `StaleStateException` is thrown. Try to change your code to:

```
try {
    item?.delete(flush: flush)
} catch (StaleStateException e) {
    log.error "Inventory: {} couldn't be deleted", item, e
}
```

or even more extreme, just catch everything (although I do not really recommend it as a long term solution):

```
try {
    item?.delete(flush: flush)
} catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error "Inventory: {} couldn't be deleted", item, e
}
```